# How to change calendar entry background based on taxonomy?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

Folks, I'm trying to figure out how to style my calendar. I was able to add color stripes based on my taxonomy, but the background of calendar entries is still that ugly yellow #ffc. What I'd like to do is to make the background the same color as the taxonomy color, only brighter/semi-transparent - for example, if the taxonomy color is #00ff00, I want to se the background of that calendar entry to #e0ffe0. I'm pretty new to Drupal and really can't figure out what's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML source of your calendar display, and try to find:

`<div class="block- (whatever)" ... >Calendar entry stuff</div>`

The CSS class name might be something like "block block-calendar block-calendar-entry" but you just want the most specific one that works, and only shows on each calendar entry.

Use CSS transparent coloration of the individual entries:

/* Colors a calendar entry lighter */

div.block-calendar-entry {

background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)

}

The first three numbers give the RGB value, and the last one gives the opacity.

Since 255, 255, 255 (maximum red, green, and blue) would be white, an opacity of 0.3 (30%) will lighten any background color that bleeds through from the parent container.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. The problem is that taxonomy color is assigned to a stripe which is a sibling of the calendar entry, not a parent. It is placed directly above the entry, not under it. So changing the transparency won't do the trick.

Comment: Are you able to install and use Views?  If you load the Taxonomy items with their associated content, it may allow you to change how Drupal outputs data.  https://www.drupal.org/project/views

Comment: Yes, I do use Views, this maybe something worth looking into, but I'm not sure what exactly I should do. Currently I just have a Calendar view which who's Calendar Entities and exposes fields Title, Date and MyTaxonomy.